# codeigniter active record get query and query without the LIMIT clause

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

im using active record, its all working ok but i want to set the **$data["totalres"]** to the total results, i mean, the same query but without the **LIMIT**

the problem is the previous statements gets unset when you do a query modifier, so i cant even add the $this->db->limit() after i get the results.

any ideas? i think its a bad practice to 'duplicate' the query just to do this

```
function get_search($start, $numrows, $filter = array())
{    

    ...

    $this->db
    ->select("emp")
    ->from('emp')
    ->join('empr', 'empr.b = empr.id', 'left')
    ->like('code', $code)
    ->limit($numrows, $start);

    ...

    $q = $this->db->get();        

    // number of rows WITHOUT the LIMIT X,Y filter
    $data["totalres"] = ???????;        

    if ($q->num_rows() > 0)
    {        
        $data["results"] = $q->result();
    } else {
        $data["results"] = array();
    }   

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: may be this 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/23648274/2664160


//ignore this comment he he

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use [`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) to get the number of rows that would have been returned sans-`LIMIT`.  Note the `,FALSE` in the `select` line.  This tells CodeIgniter not to try to escape the `SELECT` clause with backticks (because `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is not a field, and CodeIgniter doesn't realize that).

```
$this->db
->select("SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS emp", FALSE)
->from('emp')
->join('empr', 'empr.b = empr.id', 'left')
->like('code', $code)
->limit($numrows, $start);

$q = $this->db->get();
```

Then after that query is ran, we need run another query to get the total number of rows.

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS `Count`');
$data["totalres"] = $query->row()->Count;
```

Comment: thanks..i tought CI would have something ready for this but 'plain' mysql is even better

Comment: I think they don't have that built in because `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is only for MySQL, and CodeIgniter is supposed to work with all database types.

Comment: The second line in the second snippet does not seem correc, it gives errors. I'd suggest: $query = $this->db->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as Count')->row(); $result['size'] = $query->Count;

Comment: This is good solution but there is one problem in it.. If you are using MySQL DB Engine then it will work perfectly, but if you'r going to change any other DB like Oracle then this solution will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function get_search($start, $numrows, $filter = array()){    
    $tmp= $this->db
    ->select("emp")
    ->from('emp')
    ->join('empr', 'empr.b = empr.id', 'left')
    ->like('code', $code)
    ->_compile_select();

    $q= $this->db->limit($numrows, $start)->get();

    // number of rows WITHOUT the LIMIT X,Y filter

    $data["totalres"] = $this->db->query($tmp)->num_rows();

    if ($q->num_rows() > 0){        
        $data["results"] = $q->result();
    } else {
        $data["results"] = array();
    }   
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: FYI `_compile_select` is not available in CodeIgniter 2.0.3+.  https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/276

Comment: [Fixe for Issue #276](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/pull/307) by @KyleFarris

Comment: Never too late to help researchers.  `result()` unconditionally returns an array, so you don't need the `if` block.  `$data["results"] = $q->result();`

Answer (score 1):

I would actually suggest the use of CIs query caching.

To use this, you start the cache, build the query without the limits in place. Run your query to get the full count, then apply the limit and run the query to get your list for your page with the offset you need.

The cache will remember the variables that have been defined.

You can then clear the cache for subsequent queries.

Example

```
    $this->db->start_cache();

    // Where, like, having clauses in here

    $this->db->stop_cache();

    $count = $this->db->get('table')->num_rows();

    $this->db->limit('limit', 'offset');

    $result = $this->db->get('table')->result_array();

    $this->db->flush_cache();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db
->select("SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS emp", FALSE)
->from('emp')
->join('empr', 'empr.b = empr.id', 'left')
->like('code', $code)
->limit($numrows, $start); $q = $this->db->get();

$query = $this->db->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS `Count`');
$data["totalres"] = $this->db->get()->row()->Count;
```

CodeIgniter 2.1.0 not run, below code will fix it.

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS `Count`');
$objCount = $query->result_array();
$data["totalres"] = $objCount[0]['Count'];
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.