# Count rows before adding a further limit statement CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I have ran into a problem...

I have a bunch of where statments like so...

```
$this->db->where('Pool', "1");
$this->db->where('Bedrooms >=', "3");
```

Then a limit statement

```
$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
```

And finally my get statement

```
$query = $this->db->get('table-name');
```

**My problem is I need to count the results before my limit statement, to get the total rows without the limit.. So I tried this..**

```
$this->db->where('Pool', "1");
$this->db->where('Bedrooms >=', "3");

$num_rows = $this->db->count_all_results();

$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
$query = $this->db->get('table-name');
```

This counts my rows with the where statements fine.. However, the get statement now gets records without the previous where statements working.

It's not visible, but there is a large amount of code handling more where statements, and grabbing things in urls, So I'd prefer not to perform the retrieval of data twice in order to fix this...

Cheers!

Comment: You'll have to do two queries, unless you want to pull all the rows every time. The second query could just be a `SELECT COUNT(id) AS row_count FROM table WHERE conditions`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$get_data = $this->your_model->get_data();
$data     = $get_data['data'];
$count    = $get_data['count'];
```

Model

```
function get_data($limit = 10, $offset= 0)
{
    $table = 'table-name';
    $where = array('Pool' => 1, 'Beedrooms >=' 3);

    $return['data']  = $this->db->from($table)->where($where)->limit($limit, $offset)->get();
    $return['count'] = $this->db->from($table)->where($where)->count_all_results();

    return $return;
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and left the limit on the "count_all_results()" line by mistake and still got counted all items that matched my "where"... not sure if a bug or feature

EDIT: only worked while my offset == 0 I think is a bug

Answer (score 18):

I know this is an old question, but I just ran into this problem and came up with a different solution.

The idea is to take a copy of the db class before the limit and offset.

```
$this->db->where('Pool', "1");
$this->db->where('Bedrooms >=', "3");

//here we use the clone command to create a shallow copy of the object
$tempdb = clone $this->db;
//now we run the count method on this copy
$num_rows = $tempdb->from('table-name')->count_all_results();

$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
$query = $this->db->get('table-name');
```

Comment: why the shallow copy ?

Answer (score 15):

I know that's an old question but I found a pretty simple solution.

```
//do your select, from and where
$this->db->select('your selects');
$this->db->from('your table');

$this->db->where('your where');

//get the filtered rows count
//the trick is the first empty parameter and second false parameter
$filtered_count = $this->db->count_all_results('', false);

//limit your results and get the rows
$this->db->limit($length, $start);
$results = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Hope it helps someone

Comment: Great find. :+1: Works like a charm

Comment: pretty neat solution

Answer (score 5):

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('active',$status);

    //open1 here we copy $this->db in to tempdb and apply 
    //count_all_results() function on to this tempdb
    $tempdb = clone $this->db;
    $num_results= $tempdb->count_all_results();   

    // now applying limit and will get actual result 
    $this->db->limit(10);

    $this->db->get();
    $query = $this->db->last_query();
    $res = $this->db->query($query);        

    $data_array = array('num_results' => $num_results, 'results' => $res->result() );
    return $data_array;
```

Comment: Thanks bro! You saved my time.

Comment: It's not necessary to clone the DB Objetc. Simply use "$num_rows = $this->db->count_all_results('', false);" before limiting the Result.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite evident that you would need to use two different queries. It would be optimum to do this as quickly as possible using a single query, but since you need to get all the records before the second query, we need to use two queries.

However, you can optimize the first query based on the engine you use with MySQL. If you use InnoDB then you should use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <table-name>` cause the total row size is cached in InnoDB.

I believe `count_all_rows` uses `count(*)` for performance and you should be sorted using this direcctly.

With MyISAM you can use `COUNT(<column-name>)`.

So, you have a count function in your model class which returns the count for your table and then you can call the function to insert/update/get data from your database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` of mysql

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table1
WHERE
  cond1, cond2, ..., condN
LIMIT 10
```

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();

This is using mysql, you may need to check how to use it codeignitor way.

Reference:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Comment: Found that one too and it seems to be the most elegant way. Some Details are located here: https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I had the same issue and got a simpler solution than the displayed here. No need to build the query twice and no need to clone the `db class`. Just count the result without resting the query builder after you add the `where` part and then you add the `limit` and execute your query.

```
$this->db->where('Pool', 1);
$this->db->where('Beedrooms >=' 3);
$count = $this->db->count_all_results('table-name', false); // No reset query builder
$this->db->limit($limit, $offset)
$result = $this->db->get();
```

You are going to have two variables:
`$count` with the number of results and `$result` with the result.