# Codeigniter 2.1 - Count all results of search before limit

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

How can I count all results when I am doing search before limit? Do I need to make two queries (one with limit and one without limit) or this can be done in one query?
I have function like this:

```
$i = 0;
        $word = explode(' ', $word);
        $this->db->select("SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS clanak", FALSE)
        ->from('clanak')
        ->join('kategorija', 'kategorija_id = id_kategorija');
        foreach ($word as $w) :
            $i == 0 ? $this->db->like('naslov', $w) : $this->db->or_like('naslov', $w);
            $i++;
        endforeach;
        return $this->db->order_by('datum_kreiranja desc, procitan desc')->limit($limit, $offset)->get()->result_array();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to do a second query to get the results of `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

Comment: I see, but I a bit stumbled where to do second query and how to return counted result?

Comment: You can out it anywhere you want as long as you don't run another query using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` before you call it. And you get the results by using a select statement like the one above although you will probably find it easier if you use an alias to get the value `SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS num_results`.

Comment: Did you not just try to help me with the same query? [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554195/codeigniter-active-record-count-total-found-rows-with-limit-mysql)