# Codeigniter ActiveRecord duplicate,change,execute MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I am using the ActiveRecord library that comes with the PHP framework CodeIgniter. I frequently find myself needing to query the database for a number of rows using a `LIMIT` clause, but also needing to know the total number of rows I would have pulled had I not included the `LIMIT` clause. For example, this is frequently the case when I provide pagenation for many results. I only want to pull 20 records at a time, but I also need to know how many rows there are in total which match my query where clause. I need to create 2 slightly different queries, a count query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE [where_clause];
```

And a 'paged' query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE [where_clause] LIMIT 0,20;
```

Is there an elegant solution to this problem with ActiveRecord? There doesn't seem to be anything out of the box which will help me. Obviously I can write around the problem with my own PHP but it would be ideal if I could take advantage of some aspect of the library to not have to duplicate code, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [codeigniter active record get query and query without the LIMIT clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421873/codeigniter-active-record-get-query-and-query-without-the-limit-clause)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer my own question, best way is to use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` like so, Add this select call to your query:

```
 $this->db->select('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *',false);
```

And then immediately afterwards to get the count:

```
 $count = $this->db->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS count")->row('count');
```